# How to give access to Reference fields through ACLs?

Tags: servicenow

We have table Transfer Order:
[image]

This is the view from admin User.

[image]

This is the view of the user to whom I need to give read , write, create and delete access, but the two fields 'To Stockroom' and 'From Stockroom' are not visible to this user.

I have created ACLs like:
[image]

how I can make these two fields accessible to some user?
Please help me.

Comment: Does the user have read access to the referenced row (i.e. whatever "from_stockroom" refers to)? They need at least read access to the table and the display field.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the specific ACL that is failing the user's request for access, you can simply enable the **Debug Security** module. Then impersonate the user, visit the record, and scroll down the page. You'll eventually come to a line like this:

[image: ACL]

This red X indicates that a condition of the ACL was not met. Clicking the ACL (In this case, record/alm_asset.model/write) will take you to the specific security rule. Hovering over the red X will tell you what portion of the ACL was not met; the condition, the script, or the role requirement. That is what you must remedy either in the ACL, or by granting the user the necessary permissions.

I suspect in your case, that the user is able to see the record they're viewing, but does not have access to view the record or table referenced in the reference field. However, only the ACL/security debugger can tell you for sure.

To stop debugging, just click the "stop debugging" module in the app navigator, or log out of ServiceNow.